# Error in Makefile, Cannot Set Shell to /bin/bash (WSL)

Tags: make, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running make version 4.1 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu on WSL Ubuntu. I have the following [makefile](https://gist.github.com/MoHKale/9373b42ccc87a5f27d6cfa737d341be2) and I'm trying to run make with it. However it fails when I run it with the error message:

```
make: /bin/bash : Command not found
makefile:18: recipe for target 'cc' failed
make: *** [cc] Error 127
```

I checked the /bin/ folder and bash does exists so I have no idea why this isn't working. Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

GNU `make` is parsing the trailing whitespace after the `SHELL := /bin/bash` as part of the executable name. As noted in [GNU make: How to Use Variables](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html)

> You can also use them to introduce controlled leading whitespace into
>   variable values. Leading whitespace characters are discarded from your
>   input before substitution of variable references and function calls;
>   this means you can include leading spaces in a variable value by
>   protecting them with variable references, like this:
>
> ```
> nullstring :=
> space := $(nullstring) # end of the line
> ```
>
> Here the value of the variable space is precisely one space. The
>   comment `# end of the line' is included here just for clarity. Since
>   trailing space characters are not stripped from variable values, just
>   a space at the end of the line would have the same effect (but be
>   rather hard to read). If you put whitespace at the end of a variable
>   value, it is a good idea to put a comment like that at the end of the
>   line to make your intent clear. Conversely, if you do not want any
>   whitespace characters at the end of your variable value, you must
>   remember not to put a random comment on the end of the line after some
>   whitespace, such as this:
>
> ```
> dir := /foo/bar    # directory to put the frobs in
> ```
>
> Here the value of the variable dir is `/foo/bar` (with four trailing
>   spaces), which was probably not the intention. (Imagine something like
>   `$(dir)/file` with this definition!)

Comment: My god, Your a life saver. I thought there might be something wrong with my install. I knew about the whitespace feature but I thought it would auto truncate for executables like the shell. Didn't even occur to me that thats where the problem is. Thank you, this fixed it.

Comment: @MohsinKale you're welcome - TBH at first I thought it must be something WSL specific - only started digging after I tested it on native Ubuntu and got the same behavior

Comment: I agree, in my defence it doesn't help that in the error message the space is truncated but in the actual make interpreter it isn't

Comment: @MohsinKale if you look carefully you will notice it says `make: /bin/bash : Command not found` not `make: /bin/bash: Command not found` ;)

Comment: Damn, You're Right. It just looked so natural.